# How to Cluster infinispan cache in Jboss 7 1 1 Final?

Tags: spring, jboss7.x, redhat, infinispan

Bean Decleration:

```
bean id="cacheManager" class="org.infinispan.spring.provider.SpringEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean"
      p:configurationFileLocation="classpath:infinispan.xml" ..
```

infinispan.xml

```
<infinispan
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:5.1 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-5.1.xsd"
xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:5.1">

<global>
    <transport clusterName="CASCluster"/>
    <globalJmxStatistics enabled="true"/>
</global>

<default>
    <jmxStatistics enabled="true"/>
    <clustering mode="distribution">
        <hash numOwners="2" rehashRpcTimeout="120000"/>
        <sync/>
    </clustering>
</default>

<namedCache name="mtx.infinispan.global">
    <eviction strategy="LIRS" maxEntries="50000" />
</namedCache>

<namedCache name="books">
    <eviction strategy="LIRS" maxEntries="50000" />
</namedCache>

<namedCache name="scheduleprofiletemplates">
    <eviction maxEntries="1000000" strategy="LIRS" />

    <loaders passivation="false" shared="false" preload="true">
        <!-- We can have multiple cache loaders, which get chained -->

        <loader class="org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore" 
            fetchPersistentState="true" purgerThreads="3" purgeSynchronously="true"
            ignoreModifications="false" purgeOnStartup="false">
            <!-- See the documentation for more configuration examples and flags. -->
            <properties>
                <property name="location" value="/home/cas/infinispanCache" />
            </properties>

        </loader>
    </loaders>
</namedCache>
```

---

I want deploy the application Jboss cluster so that the cache created in one node  is accessible/replicated to other node also....

I am using Jboss Domain mode full-ha for the deployment....I have HornetQ, Mod_cluster working properly on the same cluster.

By googling, I cam to know that it achieving thru JNDI....Can you pls tel how to modify the XMl files to achiiev this....I have to create 4 named cache(Where to create this ? In sping config file or Jboss domain.xml).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Bean decleration as follows...

   <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.infinispan.spring.provider.SpringEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean"
          p:configurationFileLocation="classpath:infinispan.xml" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a Jboss cluster full-ha profile.
   2.Create queus on Jboss side
   3.Ovveride the SpringEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean cacheManager